# How can I delete current columns which have been inserted a bookmark using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a table,and I selected two columns and marked the selection as a bookmark?Now how can I delete it by using C#?

My codes like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Delete all columns of specific bookmark
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bookmark"></param>
public void DeleteTableColumns(string bookmark)
{
   object oBookmark = bookmark;
   if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmark)) {
      Range range = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmark).Range;
      //TODO:to be finished
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling [Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.delete(v=office.14).aspx) on the range?

Answer (score 0):

I've known how to resolve this issue,here's the code:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Delete all columns of specific bookmark
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bookmark"></param>
    public void DeleteTableColumns(string bookmark)
    {
        object oBookmark = bookmark;
        if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmark)) {
            object oCount = WdDeleteCells.wdDeleteCellsEntireColumn;
            doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmark).Select();
            app.Selection.Cells.Delete(ref oCount);
        }
    }
```